# How do I bind a dataset to a drop down box starting at the second index of the drop down box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dataset

Here's the code I have. It works. The only problem is that the first index of the drop down box gets wiped out ("Select Source Database") when I bind the data set to its data source.

I want to bind the data set and INCLUDE the first index "Select Source Database".

How can I modify my code to accomplish this?

```
protected void ddlServer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlSourceDatabases.Items.Clear();
    ddlSourceDatabases.Items.Add("Select Source Database");

    lbxSourceTables.Items.Clear();

    if (ddlSourceServers.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
       try
       {
           ddlSourceDatabases.DataSource = Database.GetDatabases(ddlSourceServers.Text);
           ddlSourceDatabases.DataTextField = "name";
           ddlSourceDatabases.DataValueField = "name";
           ddlSourceDatabases.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {               
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your item after data binding to the first position:

```
//...
ddlSourceDatabases.DataBind();
ddlSourceDatabases.Items.Insert(0, "Select Source Database");
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refatored your code, now it should work

```
protected void ddlServer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
ddlSourceDatabases.Items.Clear();
lbxSourceTables.Items.Clear();

if (ddlSourceServers.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
   try
   {
       ddlSourceDatabases.DataSource = Database.GetDatabases(ddlSourceServers.Text);
       ddlSourceDatabases.DataTextField = "name";
       ddlSourceDatabases.DataValueField = "name";
       ddlSourceDatabases.DataBind();

      ddlSourceDatabases.Items.Add("Select Source Database");

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {               
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the "Select Source Database" as a new item to your datasource as the DataTextField and null as the DataValueField. That'll fix it. When you databind to a datasource, any other values will be deleted and only the ones from your datasource will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Independent of what you added previously (in your case is the "Select Source Database" string), when you set the datasource manually you're replacing ALL the items included the previously added. So add the item before setting its datacontext (to the zero index or first position) using `dlSourceDatabases.Items.Insert(0, "Select Source Database")`